# Does reflection depend on wavelength?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, wavelength, optical-materials

I'm aware of processes like Rayleigh scattering, Compton scattering and pair production. But as these processes treat light as being particles(?) I'm not sure whether they are helpful to understand the behavior of a beam of light:

[image: img]

Well, and as you can see they would deal with one method anyway. I guess I'm more interested in reflection and transmission but on the other hand, you can also have compton scattering such that it reflects straight back to you..

However, let's say we shine light on a surface like a cornea. Is there a way to predict how much (like percentage) of the beam will be reflected directly at the cornea's surface and how much will transmit through it and travel across the eye (so we are able to detect and see)?

Does it matter whether the source is a lamp or a laser? Probably but in which way? Only in regard to the used wavelength?

Comment: The reflectivity of the cornea will for sure depend on wavelength and there are likely numerous studies on this topic because of high relevance for medical and eye-safety purposes. E.g. (but behind paywall, so couldn't check) <https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/4916/0000/Reflectivity-of-the-human-cornea-and-its-influence-on-the/10.1117/12.482991.short?SSO=1>.